# Nested shortcodes not working (2nd level nesting)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

```
[row]
[column size="eight"]
    [row]<h5>HELLO<strong>WORLD</strong></h5>[/row]
    [row]<h5>CATEGORIES: <strong>WEB / CREATIONS / INTERACTIVE DESIGN</strong></h5>[/row]
[/column]
[column size="four"]Insert your content here[/column]
[/row]
```

This is the shortcode code im using. But for some reason, the [row]...[/row] shortcode doesn't seem to work.
Heres the shortcode functon:

```
function su_column_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'size' => 'six'
            ), $atts ) );
    return '<div class="' . $size . ' columns">' . su_do_shortcode( $content, 'c' ) . '</div>';
}
function su_row_shortcode($atta = null, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="row">'.su_do_shortcode( $content, 'r').'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is not a question, but a fact.

Wordpress shortcodes can not be nested. If you need nesting, you would need to do "nesting" on your own, by applying all shortcodes on the "inner" part inside *your* shortcode *your* own.

See [*Shortcode API Limitations: Nested Shortcodes*<sup>*Codex*</sup>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes)

Comment: Sure one can not know everything, but also consider some google search. The codex most often has useful information about wordpress functionality, so worth a read and worth to search for (add "codex" to your search terms).